# Refresh previous activity on back press

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh, onbackpressed

I have an activity which shows a List of items from the server. When the list Item is clicked I open up another detail activity. On the detail activity Iam doing some changes back to the server. So when I press back button i want to refresh the previous activity to make sure the changes I made reflect.

This is what I do currently :-

```
@Override
    protected void onRestart()
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
        FetchItems fetchTask = new FetchItems();
        try {
            myFinalList = fetchTask.execute(registerContet).get();

            }
         catch (Exception e)
         {

            e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
```

Everything works fine. But when I press the back button there is a UI freeze and it does not go back to the previous screen instantly.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Actually on back press activity life cycle onResume() method get called so  write code inside onResume().

Comment: Learn http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: where is your `onBackPressed`  & `onResume` code

Comment: @SuhasBachewar onResume gets called the the beginning of the app. right now everything works fine. I just want to make sure there is no delay on backpress

Comment: listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); method will helps you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Back button and refreshing previous activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545217/back-button-and-refreshing-previous-activity)

Comment: Whats wrong with startActivityForResult? Start new activity for result, if something was changed change result as done, if result==done in previous activity notifyItemChanged

Answer (score 1):

When you start your Detail Activity, use [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)).  Then do whatever work you want in your Detail Activity and call [`setResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) and `finish()`.  Finally, back in your first activity and override [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) grab whatever data you packed before the finish() and use it to refresh your list.

Further info and examples can be found here:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities
- http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: The thing is I get a list in an activity and then pass the list to a fragment which displays it in a listview. I have the onclick event in the fragment. So OnActivityResult does not do a refresh

Comment: If you like this sort of approach but are using fragments, check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751583/794088

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a perfect use-case for an `event bus like otta,greenDao`,
BUt if you dont want to use those you can put the refresh status flag in the intent and pass it to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onRestart()
{
super.onRestart();
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```